# How does a MU-MIMO device with more antennas behave on a network with less?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking, network-adapter

If a device is MU-MIMO 4x4 and the router is 3x3 how does the device behave?

Does the MU-MIMO just not work and behaves as a SU-MIMO? Or does it drop an antenna and work as 3x3? Or does it attempt to use 4x4 but because router is only 3x3 it just sort of slows down to 3x3 and it sort of "load balances" the 4 antennas amongst the 3 available?

A while back I moved and the house didn't really accommodate a wired network easily so I went and picked up a nice 4x4 card, thinking neat why not. I've always been a little involved and interested in my network, but recently I'm getting more so since I'm here so much more and working from home. I always knew my router was only 3x3 MU-MIMO, but realized recently "well what does that mean for my computer?"

[There are a lot of diagrams about how devices with less antennas behave on a network with more](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/mu-mimo-wifi-router), but I can't seem to find any answers to a devices with more? If the device is being treated as a SU-MIMO, maybe it's worth an upgrade to get 4x4 matching router, but if it's simply handling the 4x4 device as 3x3, I'm more inclined to leave it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the diagrams you referenced and just imagine the device names reversed you can visualize the answer.  The device won't blend or "load balance" the 4 streams, it will just always have at least 1 unused MIMO stream like the router does in the 3x3 image.  If something else connects to the router and uses 1 stream, your device would have 2 used and 2 unused streams, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That make sense. Now I'm just curious, do you happen to know how it's dynamically changing the number of streams like that? Is the devices and router constantly handshaking to figure out how many streams are available?

Example, my computer has 3 streams of the router connected, the 4th stream is constantly pinging the air and getting nothing back and trying anyway? Then I pick up my phone and it starts using a stream, leaving 2 streams on my computer trying to find a new stream? Or does it somehow know it'll never get anything with that 4th stream?

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad I could offer some help. Unfortunately I can't speak intelligently at the level of detail necessary for your follow up question, so I'll leave it for someone else.